# R if else statement that depends on number of elements in a character string

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to make an if else statement that depends on the number of elements in a character string, here's my mock data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Matt Smith", "Matt L. Smith", "Sara Smith", "Sara Rose Smith"))
```

I'm trying to write this statement so that any names that contain first, middle, and last names (i.e., 3 separate words) are spit into three columns (first, middle, and last), whereas any names with just first and last only are sorted into the first and last name columns. Here's what I've tried:

```
if (any(lengths(strsplit(df1$name, "\\W+")) > 2)) {
  df1 <- df1 %>%
    separate(name, c('Collector.First.Name1', 'Collector.Middle1', "Collector.Last.Name1"))
} else {
  df1 <- df1 %>%
    separate(name, c('Collector.First.Name1', "Collector.Last.Name1"))
}
```

This outputs this data frame:

```
Collector.First.Name1 Collector.Middle1 Collector.Last.Name1
1                  Matt             Smith                 <NA>
2                  Matt                 L                Smith
3                  Sara             Smith                 <NA>
4                  Sara              Rose                Smith
```

However, the output I'm looking for would sort the names with only 2 elements into just the first and last name designations, like this:

```
Collector.First.Name1 Collector.Middle1 Collector.Last.Name1
1                  Matt              <NA>                Smith
2                  Matt                 L                Smith
3                  Sara              <NA>                Smith
4                  Sara              Rose                Smith
```

Using R 4.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add an extra space when the name has only one, which will make `separate()` create an empty middle group. Better than a space, we can use a temporary character like `'='` to avoid problems.

**If else approach with `case_when()`:**

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(name = case_when(str_count(name, " ") == 1 ~ str_replace(name, " ", "=="),
                          str_count(name, " ") > 1 ~ str_replace_all(name, " ", "=")) %>%
                  str_remove_all("\\.")) %>%
  separate(name, c("first", "middle", "last"), "=")
```

If the number of spaces (`str_count(name, " ")`) is one, we add two temporary characters. Else, we add one every time a space appears. We later remove dots because you seem to not want them. Lastly, we use the temporary character to separate the columns.

**Regex approach with `gsub()`:**

We can define a regex that can match a middle group, even if it's an empty one, and add that temporary character between them.

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(name = gsub('([A-Za-z]+) ([A-Za-z\\.]* )?([A-Za-z]+)', '\\1=\\2=\\3', name) %>%
                  str_remove_all("\\.| ")) %>%
  separate(name, c("first", "middle", "last"), "=")
```

Explaining the pattern:

- `([A-Za-z]+)` a word of any size, the first name;
- `([A-Za-z\\.]+ )?` a word of any size, that migth have a dot somewhere, and a space at the end. That whole group `(...)` might or might not be present `?`;
- `([A-Za-z]+)` a word of any size, the last name.

Later we remove extra spaces and dots, and separate the columns

**Both yield the same result:**

```
  first middle  last
1  Matt        Smith
2  Matt      L Smith
3  Sara        Smith
4  Sara   Rose Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

Witch regex match groups and `stringr` perhaps something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Matt Smith", "Matt L. Smith", "Sara Smith", "Sara Rose Smith"))

# 3 regex match groups will end up in 3 columns
str_match(df1$name, "^(\\S+)(.*\\s+)(.*)$") %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c("name", "first", "mid", "last")) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(mid = trimws(mid) %>% na_if("")) 
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   name            first mid   last 
#>   <chr>           <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 Matt Smith      Matt  <NA>  Smith
#> 2 Matt L. Smith   Matt  L.    Smith
#> 3 Sara Smith      Sara  <NA>  Smith
#> 4 Sara Rose Smith Sara  Rose  Smith
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyr`, we could use `separate_wider_*` twice specifying different `too_many`/`too_few`-arguments:

```
library(tidyr)

df1 |>
  separate_wider_delim(name, delim = " ", names = c("first", "name"), too_many = "merge") |>
  separate_wider_delim(name, delim = " ", names = c("mid", "last"), too_few = "align_end")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  first mid   last 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Matt  NA    Smith
2 Matt  L.    Smith
3 Sara  NA    Smith
4 Sara  Rose  Smith
```

Note that `separate_wider_delim` is experimental, but that similar functionalities exist in (the superseded) `separate`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `if else` statement. Just ensure you have the right regex:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  extract(name, c("first", "middle", "last"), "(\\w+) (\\S*) ?(\\b\\w+$)")

 first middle  last
1  Matt        Smith
2  Matt     L. Smith
3  Sara        Smith
4  Sara   Rose Smith
```

in Base R you could do:

```
read.csv(text = gsub(" (\\S*) ?\\b(?!$)", ",\\1,", df1$name, perl = TRUE),
    header =FALSE, col.names = c("first", "middle", "last"), na.strings = '')
  first middle  last
1  Matt   <NA> Smith
2  Matt     L. Smith
3  Sara   <NA> Smith
4  Sara   Rose Smith
```

Comment: Wow, `\b` is so useful! really simplifies the regex.