# R regular expression to split apart name strings

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe with names listed in various different formats, and I'd like to split these names into first, middle, and last name. Here's an example dataframe with different name formats:

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Matt Smith", "Matt L. Smith", "Matt Louis Smith",
                           "M. Smith", "M.L. Smith", "M.L. Smith, Jr.", "M. Smith, Jr.", "Unknown"))
```

I have code from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76316213/r-if-else-statement-that-depends-on-number-of-elements-in-a-character-string) that splits apart non-initials correctly, but it fails when the first and middle initial are both present. Here's that code and its output:

```
names <- df1 %>%
  mutate(name = gsub('([A-Za-z\\.?]+) ([A-Za-z\\.]+ )?([A-Za-z]+)?', '\\1=\\2=\\3', name)) %>%
  separate(name, c("Collector.First.Name1", "Collector.Middle1", "Collector.Last.Name1"), "=")

Collector.First.Name1 Collector.Middle1 Collector.Last.Name1
1                  Matt                                  Smith
2                  Matt               L.                 Smith
3                  Matt            Louis                 Smith
4                    M.                                  Smith
5                  M.L.                                  Smith
6                  M.L.                             Smith, Jr.
7                    M.                             Smith, Jr.
8               Unknown
```

My ideal output would be this, with the initials correctly split:

```
Collector.First.Name1 Collector.Middle1 Collector.Last.Name1
1                  Matt                                  Smith
2                  Matt               L.                 Smith
3                  Matt            Louis                 Smith
4                    M.                                  Smith
5                    M.               L.                 Smith
6                    M.               L.            Smith, Jr.
7                    M.                             Smith, Jr.
8               Unknown
```

Using R 4.2.2

Comment: Your issue seems to be when there is `.` but no space between the first and middle initials. I would suggest a pre-processing step to insert a space after any dots followed by a non-space, perhaps  `gsub(pattern = "(\\.)([^ ])", replacement = "\\1 \\2", x = name)` (untested).

Comment: If the comments suggest a solution, it's better to post it as an answer rather than editing your question to include the answer ...

Comment: Are the columns of a fixed width?  For example, the first-name ends on index 23, every time?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `extract` from `tidyr`; basically a one-liner:

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  extract(name,
          into = c("first", "middle", "last"),
          regex = "(\\w+\\.?)\\s*(?:([^\\s,]+)\\s)?(?:(\\w+(?:,\\sJr\\.)?))?")
    first middle       last
1    Matt             Smith
2    Matt     L.      Smith
3    Matt  Louis      Smith
4      M.             Smith
5      M.     L.      Smith
6      M.     L. Smith, Jr.
7      M.        Smith, Jr.
8 Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the comment by Gregor - including a pre-processing step to insert a space after any dots followed by a non-space

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(name = gsub(pattern = "(\\.)([^ ])","\\1 \\2", name))

names <- df2 %>%
  mutate(name = gsub('([A-Za-z\\.?]+) ([A-Za-z\\.]+ )?([A-Za-z]+)?', '\\1=\\2=\\3', name)) %>%
  separate(name, c("Collector.First.Name1", "Collector.Middle1", "Collector.Last.Name1"), "=")


Collector.First.Name1 Collector.Middle1 Collector.Last.Name1
1                  Matt                                  Smith
2                  Matt               L.                 Smith
3                  Matt            Louis                 Smith
4                    M.                                  Smith
5                    M.               L.                 Smith
6                    M.               L.            Smith, Jr.
7                    M.                             Smith, Jr.
8               Unknown
```